# Натянуть картинку из скрипта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно натянуть на GameObject картинку при помощи скрипта - ну как просто если бы перетащили бы эту картинки на GameObject. Но скриптом. Game Object -ы у нас в массиве, обращатся к ним легко. 
Вот например так я ставлю цвет на GameObject, находящийся в массиве piece

```
 pieces[1].GetComponent<pieceController>().setColor(Red);
 public void setColor(Color newColor) {
    myColor = newColor;
    this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = myColor;
```

Вот как мне поставить не цвет а картинку какую нибудь из Assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказалось достаточно просто

```
public Material mymaterial;

pieces[1].GetComponent<pieceController>().setColor(Red);
public void setColor(Color newColor) {
myColor = newColor;
this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mymaterial;
this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = myColor;
```